# How get float number with no rounded number in java

Tags: java

I have this float 98.01645 and I'm getting 98.02 with this function:

```
    String lastCredit = String.format("%.2f", AppSingleton.getInstance().credit);
```

That I want is get 98.01 (only two decimals or not rounded number). I'm trying but I can't get the way to do it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing it manually:

```
String lastCredit = String.format("%.2f", java.lang.Math.floor(100.0*AppSingleton.getInstance().credit)*0.01);
```

Multiplying by 100.0 to move the decimal point two to the right, then rounding down, then moving the decimal point two to the left by multiplying with 0.01.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
    String lastCredit = String.format("%.2f",Math.floor((98.01645 * 100)) / 100);
    System.out.println(lastCredit);
```

You basically multiply the value by 100 because you need 2 numbers after the decimal and round down that value. After you have the result you divide it by 100 again.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code instead of `String lastCredit = String.format("%.2f", AppSingleton.getInstance().credit);`

```
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    String lastCredit = decimalFormat.format(f);
```

Comment: is returning 98,2 and not 98,01

Comment: @S.P. Updated the code Please check.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem +1 for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

I would not call this elegant, but you can just use String.format to get 3 decimal places and remove the last using substring:

```
String lastCredit = String.format("%.3f", AppSingleton.getInstance().credit);
lastCredit = lastCredit.substring(0, lastCredit.length() - 1);
```

Comment: This assumes that "%.2f" gives you trailing zeros, which I cannot test, because I am on mobile right now.